# mongoDB 4.0 / Compass: No hostname or hostnames provided in connection string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

After coping the URI from cloud.mongodb, I'm trying to connect via [compass](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/compass-connection/) (1.15.1) on windows 10, but I'm getting this strange error:

> No hostname or hostnames provided in connection string

This is what I've done in the process (as you may see, I've filled out the **Hostname** input):

### 1. Copied the URI:

[image]

### 2. Pasted inside compass:

[image]

### 3. Added my IP to white list

---

UPDATE:

After setting the **SRV Record** as true, the error has been changed to:

> URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to first copy to clipboard the connection string and then go to the MongoDB Compass and create a new connection (Connect -> Connect to..). The software will automatically complete the fields with that you had copied.

Answer (score 2):

I started it by removing 'http://' prefix from Host address.

Answer (score 2):

First copy the link altas gives you .

It might be the case when you have "@" in your password field. It breaks you password and alter the url for the host.

For eg : if your password contains "@" replace it with %40

I solved my problem with this.

It might be problem from some users.

Hope it helps